# Retrieve pthread_create's arg from outside the thread?

Tags: multithreading, pthreads

This is related to [How to assign unique ids to threads in a pthread wrapper?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/24883629/608639) and [The need for id_callback when in a multithread environment?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/30159104/608639).

When we need to differentiate among *unique* threads, we cannot use functions like [`pthread_self`](http://linux.die.net/man/3/pthread_self) because thread ids are reused. In those problems, it was suggested to use a monotonically increasing counter to provide a unique id due to counter potential thread id reuse. The counter is then passed to the thread by way of `arg` in `pthread_create`.

I don't think we can maintain a map of external thread ids to unique ids because of the reuse problem. The same thread id could have multiple unique ids.

How do we retrieve the `arg` passed to `pthread_create` from ***outside*** the thread? Is it even retrievable?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I don't think we can maintain a map of external thread ids to unique
>   ids because of the reuse problem. The same thread id could have
>   multiple unique ids.

You can, as long as in this map you only keep the external thread IDs corresponding to currently running threads.  When a thread exits, you remove it from the map.

The user of the map obviously only cares about currently running threads, since apparently the only way it has to identify the thread it wants is the external thread ID.

Comment: Thanks caf. Is there any way to ask for the `arg` back? That is, given a thread id that could have been reused, how do we get it to tell us its `arg`?

Comment: No, the only way is to stash that association in a data structure somewhere.